# Record active cell address in new sheet on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I want a button click to

- record the address of the active cell I have selected in sheet 1, and place it into the next empty row in Column "B" on sheet 2.
- On the button click as well, I wish for a `MsgBox` to display the corresponding row of Column "A", which contains reference numbers.

So far I have a working button, but my coding abilities are limited and this is all I have:

```
Private Sub CellReferenceBtn_Click()
MsgBox "The Active Cell Row and Column is " & ActiveCell(Row + 1, Column + 1).Address
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us what's not working so far?

Comment: The code I have in this post works fine, however I only wrote it to determine if gave me the active cell address. I am stuck on where to go from there though.

I have no further coding from there to enter the cell address into the column as I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Private Sub CellReferenceBtn_Click()
    With ActiveCell
        Sheet2.[offset(b1,counta(b:b),)] = .Address
        MsgBox Sheet1.Cells(.Row, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Excel Hero, your code works as well! I appreciate the help

Comment: using `CountA` to detect the first blank cell presumes no blanks in the data  - not recommended.

Comment: @brettdj So David, really? Sigh... If handling blanks were part of the design spec (not the case here) I use this instead: `Sheet2.[index(b:b,1+match("*",b:b,-1))] = .Address`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Sub AddForm()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

'check active sheet is sheet 1
If ActiveCell.Parent.Name = ws1.Name Then
    ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ActiveCell.Address
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear on whether you require the worksheet name as well as the cell address. The worksheet name would make a full cell range address but if your intention is to use only the cell portion for something else then the worksheet name will just get in the way. Here are three possibilities.

```
'just the cell address without the worksheet name
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
            Selection(1).Address
        'alternate for a larger selection of cells
        '.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
            Selection.Address
        'pass focus back to the worksheet cells
        Selection.Select
    End With
End Sub

'cell range and the worksheet name
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim addr As String
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        addr = Selection(1).Address(external:=True)
        'alternate for a larger selection of cells
        addr = Selection.Address(external:=True)
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Chr(39) & _
            Replace(addr, _
              Mid(addr, InStr(1, addr, Chr(91)), _
                InStr(1, addr, Chr(93)) - InStr(1, addr, Chr(91)) + 1), _
                vbNullString)
        'pass focus back to the worksheet
        Selection.Select
    End With
End Sub

'full external path, worksheet name and cell range
'you can use this locally and it will abbreviate itself to what is necessary
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
            Selection(1).Address(external:=True)
        'alternate for a larger selection of cells
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
            Selection.Address(external:=True)
        Selection.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Jeeped. It's all sorted now :)